# How can I achieve automated ground control point detection to move 10 out of 100 images from the input directory to the output directory?

Tags: python

I started by researching existing image processing libraries and frameworks that offer feature detection algorithms.
I anticipated that the script would be able to automatically select and move the 10 images containing the ground control points to the output directory.